# Trigger for insert problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, permissions, triggers

I'm using mssql server 2008 and having a problem with a trigger. Now, i have this aspx page, which has a stored procedure working in a button click, and that stored procedure has an execute permission for the user, lets says "x". this procedure insert some values to a table on one db. and that table has a trigger for insert, which should insert those values to some tables at other databases.

As i said, the stored procedure has an execute permission for the user "x", and the same user have insert/update/delete/select permissions on the tables that the trigger should do the insert to.

But when someone with an "x" permission starts the procedure, he/she gets this exception message : `Cannot find the object "DatabaseName..table_name" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`

But i know that database and table name is correct.

So i am thinking, maybe it has something to do with the table having permissions but i am not sure of course.

Any help with be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: First is this reference in the trigger or the stored proc? Second have you tried running the proc by a user that has full database permissions?

Comment: it is in the trigger, stored proc does not do any insert to that table. I havent tried with another user yet, but creating all the tables and triggers in the test server now, so will try on it.

Comment: well i have tried it myself (system admin) and proc,trigger,page.. everything is working normal. so i guess this means nothing wrong with the page or proc or trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have same tables with different schemas? Your message doesn't indicate schema used.
Or your user has not other database access right? It is actually possible that user has rights to table, but his access to database itself is disabled.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply. but no difference between the schemas, and the user has access, no problem there also. cause the system has like 400+ aspx pages, 20+ databases, and the user is working normally in all of them.

Comment: apperantly the problem was occuring while doing "set identity_insert on" . removed those lines and it worked. thanks for the reply.